# Need a help on how to sort the list based on volume

Tags: c#

Here,a list of boxes which has length,height,depth and volume has been created. Now, i need these boxes in a sorted order according to the volume. kindly provide me an idea how i can sort the boxes only considering the volume. I am using vs2008, linq is not working here. so is there any other solution.

```
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/containervalues.txt"))

                            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                // create new instance of container for each line in file
                                Box box = new Box();
                                List<Box> listofboxes = new List<Box>();
                                string[] Parts = line.Split(' ');
                                // set non-static properties of container
                                box.bno = Parts[0];
                                box.length = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[1]);
                                box.height = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[2]);
                                box.depth = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[3]);
                                box.volume = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[4]);
                                // add container to list of containers
                                listofboxes.Add(box);

                            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

You will need to use Linq.

```
listOfBoxes = listOfBoxes.OrderBy(x => x.volume).ToList();
```

Comment: i am using vs2008. here linq is not working. Is there any solution other than this.

Comment: mmm, maybe do your own sort method. Checking only the volume. Something like an insertionSort but made by your with a Box ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Box> sortedList = listofboxes.OrderBy(x => x.volume);
```

Answer (score 0):

.. or you can order by descending

```
listOfBoxes = listOfBoxes.OrderByDescending(p => p.volume).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a delegate as an argument for the Sort method of the Generic List:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace sortVolumen
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<box> BoxList = new List<box> { 
            new box { Width = 2, Height = 2, Depth = 2},
            new box { Width = 3, Height = 3, Depth = 3},
            new box { Width = 1, Height = 1, Depth = 1},
        };
        foreach (box myBox in BoxList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myBox.Volumen);
        }
        BoxList.Sort(delegate(box a, box b) { return a.Volumen < b.Volumen ? -1 : 1;});
            Console.WriteLine("after comparing");
            foreach (box myBox in BoxList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myBox.Volumen);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class box
    {
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Depth { get; set; }
        public double Volumen {
            get { return Width * Height * Depth; }
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can check [these](http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/simoneb/archive/2007/06/20/How-to-sort-a-generic-List_3C00_T_3E00_.aspx) ways to achieve the same behaviour.